# How do I tell the address book picker which fields to fill out?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, ios5

I am VERY new with iOS development.  So, please make your response as exact and basic as possible.

I have a form with two (at the moment - there could be more) fields that will have a button next to each that allows the user to select a contact from the iPad address book and fill the relevant field with the first and last name from the address book.

[image: Basic Form Mockup]

[The example code I have](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/QuickStart.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH2-SW1) got me to the point that I can fill in the Contact Name.  However, I would like to be able to click on the 'Browse Contacts' button next to Referred By, and have it use the same functions to fill in the referred by name.  I see that the getContactName function has the sender parameter.  So, I could easily tell which of the two buttons (or others later) were clicked.

But, when I pick from the address book, how do I know which button was clicked in the peoplePickerNavigationController or fillContactName functions?

```
- (IBAction)getContactName:(id)sender {

    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker =
    [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}


- (void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker {
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController: (ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
      shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {

    [self fillContactName:person];

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:
(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
      shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
                                property:(ABPropertyID)property
                              identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier
{
    return NO;
}


- (void)fillContactName:(ABRecordRef)person
{
    NSString* firstName = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person,
                                                                    kABPersonFirstNameProperty);

    NSString *test = [firstName stringByAppendingString:@" "];

    NSString* lastName = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person,
                                                                         kABPersonLastNameProperty);

    NSString *fullName = [test stringByAppendingString:lastName];

    self.contactName.text = fullName;

}
```

Comment: On a side note, are you sure you do not want to use the "ABRecordCopyCompositeName()" function instead of manually putting together first and last names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it.

First, assign your "Browse Contacts" button unique int values for their `tag` property when they are created (or in the storyboard, if you are using storyboards) so that you can tell them apart in your `getContactName:` method.  I would suggest setting tag=0 for the first button and tag=1 for the second button.

Then add a new property to your ViewController class that will store a pointer to the target text field after the button is clicked.  (Be sure to @synthesize in your .m file)

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *targetTextField;
```

In `getContactName:`, inspect the sender object and use its `tag` value to set the pointer appropriately.  (Note that the sender will be the UIButton object that the user clicked).

```
- (IBAction)getContactName:(id)sender {

    ...

    switch(sender.tag) {
        case 0:
            self.targetTextField = self.contactName;
            break;
        case 1:
            self.targetTextField = self.referredBy;
            break;
        default:
            self.targetTextField = nil;
    }           

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}
```

Then in `fillContactName:`, set the text value to the text field at the targetTextField which you have previously set.

```
- (void)fillContactName:(ABRecordRef)person
{
    NSString* firstName = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person,kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    NSString* lastName = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person,kABPersonLastNameProperty);

    self.targetTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstName, lastName];
}
```

Note that I have used the `NSString` class method `stringWithFormat:` to make your fillContactName code more concise.  This is a commonly used method in a case like this.